# Calling a JavaScript file function from script tag in a Visual Studio Flask project

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a Flask web page that is using a library that do not load properly when the Flask decorator '@app.after_request' is used. Is there a way to disable that decorator only for certain pages?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own decorator function that checks for the request path or just check in another function.

```
@app.route('/whatever/path')
def check_func():
    if request.path == "doesn't/work":
        return view_func()
    else:
        return app.after_request(view_func)
```

I'm not sure if this is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition in your @app.after_request decorator to exit it if the path in request is the one you want to exclude from decorator.

```
@app.after_request
def myAfterRequest():
  if ( request.path == 'path/to/exclude' ):
    return
  #decorator code
  return
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your replies. Just a side note (because it took me a while to figure out why :-)): For those that are also using 'request' from 'urllib' in addition to 'flask', the proposed solutions only works if you make aliases. This will work:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
```

This will not work:

```
from urllib import request
from flask import Flask, render_template
```